# Steinhauss theorem and sums of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

> $Proposition:$ If  $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ lebesgue measurable sets such that 
>   $0<μ(A),μ(B)< \infty$,then $A+B$ contains an interval.

I found a proof of this proposition using Steinhauss Theorem and i would  like if someone can explain me some steps in this proof that i don't understand.

$PROOF:$

Let $G\supset A$ ,$G= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ a union of intervals with rational endpoints such that $μ(G) \leqslant \frac{4}{3}μ(Α)$.

We see that $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A \cap I_n)$ and we can easily deduce that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}μ(I_n) \leqslant \frac{4}{3}μ(Α) \leqslant \frac{4}{3}μ\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}μ(A \cap I_n)$$.

Thus exists $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $μ(A \cap I_{n_1}) \geqslant \frac{3}{4} μ(I_{n_1})$.$(1)$

Applying the same argument for the set $B$ we can find $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that   $μ(B \cap I_{n_2}) \geqslant \frac{3}{4} μ(I_{n_2})$.$(2)$

Because of the fact that $μ(I_{n_1}),μ(I_{n_2}) \in \mathbb{Q}$, we can partition $I_{n_1},I_{n_2}$ into $m$ and $n$ respectively consecutive subintervals

$Step 1:$ From $(1),(2)$ we can find intervals $I_0,J_0$ such that $μ(Ι_0)=μ(J_0)$ such that $$μ(B \cap J_0) \geqslant \frac{3}{4} μ(J_0)$$

and also $$μ(A \cap I_0) \geqslant \frac{3}{4} μ(I_0)$$

$Step2:$ In other words there exists an interval $I$ centered at $0$  and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $$μ(B-y \cap I) \geqslant \frac{3}{4} μ(I)$$

$$ μ(A-x \cap I) \geqslant \frac{3}{4} μ(I)$$

It follows that $μ(B-y \cap A-x \cap I) \geqslant \frac{1}{2} μ(I)>0$

$Step3:$ Let $C=(A-x) \cap (B-y)$
If we apply Steinhauss theorem to $C-C$ we deduce that $A-B$ contains an interval.

Finally we deduce that $A-(-B)=A+B$ contains an interval.

Can someone explain me step1 and step2??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are $(1)$ and $(2)$ ?

Comment: Also, not so clear to me what the $\mu$ in the rightmost term of the first inequality is (the one outside $\sum$)

Comment: i wrote (1) and (2) in the proof

Comment: it is clear  ,think about it

Comment: there is at least one interval that makes the inequality true,because if it does not exist such interval then the inequality would not be valid

Comment: the inequality with sums of course